# Unittest for Binary Search Tree (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, binary-search-tree, python-unittest

This might be a really dumb question (I've been working on this code for a long time now) but I'm working on a unites for my binary search tree class I created and I'm running into some problems with it. I did some testing in a console to see if my BST class is basically functional, and thankfully it is. It's the unit test that's giving me problems.

Here's the code I've done so far:

```
import unittest

from Binary_Search_Tree import Binary_Search_Tree

class BST_Tester(unittest.TestCase):

  def setup(self):
       self.BST = Binary_Search_Tree()
       self.seq = range(100)

  def test_empty_BST(self):
      self.BST.in_order()
      self.assertEqual('[ ]', str(self.__BST)), 'Empty binary search tree' \
                    + ' should print as [ ]'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

The error I'm getting is `AttributeError: 'BST_Tester' object has no attribute 'BST'` and I'm not really sure where that is coming from. Maybe I'm just lacking understanding of how the unit test works but in any case, any insight anyone might have into how I can make sure that my unittest gets off on the right track would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup` method needs to be renamed to `setUp`.

Comment: I just fixed that and unfortunately am still getting the same error message

Comment: Is it the same error message? I see you have `str(self.__BST)` in your code, but `self.__BST` is not defined anywhere, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yep, that was it. I still have to work out a bunch of other errors, but at least I'm on the right track now. Thanks!